# Reconciling the Rejection Region for the Rao Score Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

For the Rao Score Test, we usually reject for large values of the score when are testing $H_0: \theta = \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta > \theta_0.$ I am confused why we reject for large values, instead of for small (negative) values of the score.

There are two ways of looking at this, and I am getting confused about how to reconcile the two and whether there are some logical flaws in my argument.

Suppose that $$\ell_\theta(X) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \text{log}(p_\theta(X))$$ is the log likelihood evaluated at some data point $X$. So the score statistic is given by $$\sum_{i=1}^n \ell_\theta(X_i).$$ Now, the point is that the expectation of $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ell_\theta(X)$$ is the negative Fisher Information (which is positive), and hence the expectation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ell_\theta(X)$ should be negative. This implies that the Score Statistic is (in expectation) decreasing in $\theta.$ Therefore, it seems that we want to reject the null when the score is small, not large. This is because if the score is small, we expect that $\theta$ is large, since the score statistic is decreasing in $\theta$, and so it's more likely that the alternative is true.

One could also look at it like this. We know that the likelihood ratio test, i.e. rejecting when the statistic $\frac{L_n(\theta_0+h)}{L_n(\theta_0)} > C$ for some constant $C$, is optimal for simple alternatives. Taking the logarithm of both sides, we reject when $$\text{log} \left(L_n(\theta_0+h)  \right) - \text{log} \left( L_n(\theta_0) \right) > \text{log}(C).$$ Taylor expanding, then roughly speaking we reject exactly when $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \text{log}( p_{\theta_0}(X_i) ) > \text{log}(C)$$ (plus some error terms).

This way of thinking about it seems to give the right idea. But then what is wrong with the previous logic, when considering tha the score is a decreasing function of $\theta$?

Comment: I am confused by this question, because you appear to conflate the *derivative* of the log likelihood with respect to the parameter with the log likelihood itself.  It's a little hard to tell, because you don't describe or define many of your terms, but the English text and the mathematics don't look like they match.